# vector and dimension vecotr with itself has a specific data type

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array

I need to vector with, boolean, std:string and int, I googled and multidimensional vector defined as :

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::vector <std::vector<int> > > a;
```

But it has problem for me, it has just one data type, I found pair:

```
std::vector<std::pair<bool,float> >  a;
```

but std::pair has problem and can't define more two dimension.

question:
how can i define multidimensional vector with each dimension has a specific data type?
note: i need to 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use std::tuple

```
std::vector<std::tuple<bool, std::string, int>>
```

But this is not a multidimentional vector. its a linear vector of tuples.

Comment: This is `C++11`, you should note that.

Comment: @Kiril: Or you use Boost's `tuple` class.

Comment: @Xeo - correct, but I'd mention that, too (here's `std::tuple`)

Comment: @seg_fault the comments explain why. Read them.

Comment: @yuri kilochek: this is ok, i used -std=c++11 and defined : `std::tuple <bool, std::string, int> packetStateStack;`

Comment: well done, i used : `std::vector<std::tuple <bool, std::string, int> > packetStateStack;`

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename First, typename Second, typename Third>
struct triplet
{
   triplet()
   {
   }
   triplet(const First& f, const Second& s, const Third& t):
      first(f), second(s), third(t)
   {
   }
   First first;
   Second second;
   Third third;
};

template<typename First, typename Second, typename Third>
triplet make_triplet(const First& f, const Second& s, const Third& t)
{
   return triplet(f, s, t);
}
```

or of course, if you have C++11 support - use `std::tuple<Args...>`, `boost::tuple` if can use boost and have no C++11 support.

Answer (score 1):

If the only problem with `std::pair` is lack of more then 2 dimension you can use vector of `std::tuple` (c++ 11) or `boost::tuple`. Or just create your own struct

Answer (score 1):

How about a `std::pair` containing both a value and a vector? I.e.

```
std::vector<std::pair<bool, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, str::vector<int>>>>>
```

Comment: i think to prevent to problem with push_back but i test it, it's good suggestion.

Comment: I put spaces to avoiding errors: `std::vector<std::pair <bool, std::vector <std::pair <std::string, std::vector <int> > > > > packetStateStack;` But i will test today.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
struct mytype {
    bool a;
    std::string str;
    int num;
};

std::vector<mytype>
```

?

Comment: It's mistake, Because str has a dynamic len, and structure need to static len, i have experienced it already.You get extra data from memory or overlap data.If i had just int and bool , you say correct.

Comment: Hmm, im not sure if its true. std::string isnt just a pointer?

Comment: Can you post any source which documents that? Becouse i cant.